# How to unit test a function with a static call

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine, mockery, dbal

I have a function I am writing that uses the Doctrine DBAL system. This uses a static function to connect as follows:

`$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);`

I want to unit test this functionality with a mock.

```
public function openNewConnection(string $database_name): Connection
{
       try {
            // some logic where I check the validity of the connection
            $this->connection = DriverManager::getConnection($connection_params, $config);
            break;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // catch the different errors that could be created
        }
    return $this->connection;
}
```

I cannot use dependency injection as a way round this as:

- I am dynamically generating `$connectionParams` : I need to make the call here
- there is no (proper) way to non statically call this function : I would just be moving the problem elsewhere

I've been working in phpunit, and I've also had a look at mockery. I don't really see how I am meant to make this work:

This mockery test doesn't work, but I'm unsure of how it should:

```
public function testConnect(): void
{
    // mocked connection return
    $mocked_connection = new Connection([], $this->driver);

    // use Mockery to simulate static call
    $driver_manager = Mockery::mock('alias:\Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager');
    $driver_manager->shouldReceive('getConnection')
                   ->once()
                   ->andReturn($mocked_connection);

    $database = new Database($this->database_configuration_file);
    $database->openNewConnection('test_db_cluster_01');

    $this->assertEquals($mocked_connection, $database->getConnection());
}
```

From what I can see, the $database isn't even aware of $driver_manager, so I don't see how the mocking would happen.

Here's my question:

- Is it even possible to test a function called statically like this?
- If so, is mockery a/the way to do this?
- If so, what is wrong with my above test?

Comment: (that's not an answer) Actually, you can use dependency injection in your case. Instead of calling `DriverManager::getConnection()` you can use `$this->connectionFactory->getConnection($connectionParams)`. Now you can inject (and mock in tests) the `$connectionFactory`.

Comment: Nope, because the $connectionParams are not externally known. The aim of the openNewConnection function is to parse over multiple connection parameters and connect. While I could factor the "connection bit" out to a separate function, it doesn't stop the fact that the connection is still static. I want to mock the static call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible.
2. Yes, Mockery (as well as PHPUnit itself) can do this (using "fake autoloading"). Check [this article](http://miljar.github.io/blog/2014/01/29/phpunit-testing-static-calls/) for more information.
3. I didn't find any problems in your test. Please, check this [repo](https://github.com/kaduev13/so-example-mocking-static). I tried to reproduce your problem, but everything goes OK.

Comment: Marking as correct. Some good info. I see why my Connection is failing though... I'm then running further methods on the Connection, which DOES attempt a DB connection.